# jsp Exception error

Tags: java, html, jsp

i get an error "17 in the jsp file: /index.jsp Void methods cannot return a value" i think my exception code is wrong. i don't know how to return an empty string when the user doesn't enter any number . any suggestions

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*"%><%@
page import="java.util.*"%><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<%
    String sum = (String) session.getAttribute("sum");

            sum = "5";
            session.setAttribute("sum",sum);

    int isum = Integer.parseInt(sum);
    try {
    isum=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("number"));
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {return "";}      
    if(request.getParameter("number")!=null && Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("number"))==isum)
    {
     if(request.getParameter("submit") != null){
            out.print("Hello");}
    }
  %>

  <body>
    <title>MAIN</title>
    <form action="index.jsp" method="post">
    Enter 5 = <input type="text" name="number">
    <input type="submit" value="continue" name="submit">
    </form>


 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

All code you write into your JSP will be compiled into the `_jspService` method. As you can see below, the signature has `void` return type.

```
public void _jspService(HttpServletRequest request, 
   HttpServletResponse  response) 
     throws IOException, ServletException {

}
```

You should remove the `return` statement at the below line:

```
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {return "";}
```

Since you're dealing with web pages, instead of `return`ing a value, you should show the user an appropriate message. In your case, it will be an error message.

```
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    out.println("Error!");
}
```

### Most Importantly

You should not use scriptlets in any JSP code you write in 2012. Learn about more advanced techniques such as JSTL and do consider using Servlets too.

Comment: i still get an error if the user doesn't enter anything and clicks on "continue" Error: "An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 18"

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding a basic programming concept: a void method can't return any value. Check this line:

```
catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    return "";
}
```

There's your error. A JSP can't return a value. Instead, you should do something with the exception like post it in your log. for now, I'll just print it in the console:

```
catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    System.out.println("Error parsing the number: " + nfe.getMessage());
}
```